# Lubricating inside valve tappets/shims

Tags: valve, lubrication, valve-lifter

Toyota engines come with tappets to shim between the valve rods and the camshaft. They look like small cylinders and are about the size of 2 oz shot glasses.

[image]

When installing them on top of the rod stems, is it necessary or even recommended to lubricate inside the tappet (or on top of the valve stems) with engine oil?

Comment: Most fun is sorting the calculations to get the clearance correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've not worked on a Toyota engine like this but the same system is common on motorcycle engines.  I generally apply a drop of motor oil to the top of the valve stem and another one on the outside of the bucket so that it slides into the opening easily.

Just be careful that you don't get any dirt or grit on these parts and you should be ok.